# Global variables slowing down PyParsing

Tags: python, python-3.x, parsing, pyparsing

When using Pyparsing to parse a file it's taking around a minute to parse Ex1 and around 15s to parse Ex2. The only difference is that in Ex1 the variables used by PyParsing are declared as globals before the class. In Ex2 the variables are declared inside each method individually (ex. `def parse_components(self)`). Is this expected? If yes, what's the explanation?

#### Ex1 (parsing time: ~ 60s):

```
import modules
import pyparsing as pp
from collections import defaultdict
from multiprocessing import (Process, Manager, Event)

# GLOBALS for PyParsing
EOL = pp.LineEnd().suppress()
linebreak = pp.Suppress(";" + pp.LineEnd())
identifier = pp.Word(pp.alphanums + '._“!<>/[]$#$%&‘*+,/:<=>?@[\]^_`{|}~')
number = pp.pyparsing_common.number
word = pp.Word(pp.alphas)
LPAR = pp.Suppress('(')
RPAR = pp.Suppress(')')
ORIENT = (pp.Keyword('N')
        | pp.Keyword('S')
        | pp.Keyword('E')
        | pp.Keyword('W')
        | pp.Keyword('FN')
        | pp.Keyword('FS')
        | pp.Keyword('FE')
        | pp.Keyword('FW'))
pt = LPAR + pp.OneOrMore(number | pp.Keyword('*')) + RPAR  # pair of x,y

class DEF():
    def __init__(self, Base):
        self.mydict = lambda: defaultdict(self.mydict)
        ...
        ...
        self.ignore_nets = True
        self.ignore_nets_route = False
        # Each list is a new process. Careful with dependencies.
        # eg. 'dbuPerMicron' must be executed before the others, but it can be after 'design'
        self.sections_grp = [['design', 'dbuPerMicron', 'diearea'],
                             ['components'],
                            ]
        if not self.ignore_nets:
            self.sections_grp.append(['nets'])
        self.n_elems_sections_grp = sum([len(x) for x in self.sections_grp])
        self.counter = modules.SharedCounter(0)
        self.events = [Event()]
        self.design = ''
        modules.debug_log.print_repr([self.__repr__()])

    #
    def run(self):
        for curr_file in self.def_file_design:
            ifile = open(curr_file,'r')
            file_string = ifile.read()
            ifile.close()
            self.parse_all(file_string)

    # Create a process for each section to parse
    def parse_all(self, file_string):
        manager = Manager()
        shared_dict = manager.dict()
        jobs = []
        for sections in self.sections_grp:
            p = Process(target=self.parse_sections, args=(sections, file_string, shared_dict))
            jobs.append(p)
            p.start()

        # Wait for the workers to finish
        for job in jobs:
            job.join()

        for sections in self.sections_grp:
            for section in sections:
                getattr(self, 'handle_' + section)(shared_dict)


    # Spawn the processes from each group of self.sections_grp
    def parse_sections(self, sections, file_string, shared_dict):
        for section in sections:
            to_parse = getattr(self, 'parse_' + section)
            for t, s, e in to_parse().scanString(file_string):
                shared_dict.update(t.asDict())
                break

    # Parse the DESIGN section of a .DEF file
    def parse_design(self):
        ...
        return design

    # Parse the UNITS DISTANCE MICRONS section of a .DEF file
    def parse_dbuPerMicron(self):
        ...
        return dbuPerMicron

    # Parse the DIEAREA section of a .DEF file
    def parse_diearea(self):
        ...
        return diearea

    # Parse the COMPONENTS section of a .DEF file
    def parse_components(self):
        self.events[0].wait()  # Wait for event[0] to finish
        components_id = pp.Keyword('COMPONENTS')
        end_components_id = pp.Keyword("END COMPONENTS").suppress()
        begin_comp = pp.Suppress(pp.Keyword('-'))
        ws_comp = pp.Suppress(pp.Keyword('+'))  # parameter division in components

        # compName
        compName = (identifier('comp_name') + identifier('cell')
                   ).setResultsName('compName')

        ...
        ...
        ...

        subcomponent = pp.Group(begin_comp
                                + compName
                                + pp.Optional(EEQMASTER)
                                + pp.Optional(SOURCE)  # & because it can be in any order
                                + pp.Optional(PLACEMENT)
                                + pp.Optional(MASKSHIFT)
                                + pp.Optional(HALO)
                                + pp.Optional(ROUTEHALO)
                                + pp.Optional(WEIGHT)
                                + pp.Optional(REGION)
                                + pp.ZeroOrMore(PROPERTY)
                                + pp.Suppress(linebreak)
                               ).setResultsName('subcomponents', listAllMatches=True)

        components = pp.Group(pp.Suppress(components_id)
                                          + number('numComps')
                                          + pp.Suppress(linebreak)
                                          + pp.OneOrMore(subcomponent)
                                          + pp.Suppress(end_components_id)
                             ).setResultsName('COMPONENTS')

        return components
```

#### Ex2 (parsing time: ~ 15s):

```
import modules
import pyparsing as pp
from collections import defaultdict
from multiprocessing import (Process, Manager, Event)

class DEF():
    def __init__(self, Base):
        self.mydict = lambda: defaultdict(self.mydict)
        ...
        ...
        self.ignore_nets = True
        self.ignore_nets_route = False
        # Each list is a new process. Careful with dependencies.
        # eg. 'dbuPerMicron' must be executed before the others, but it can be after 'design'
        self.sections_grp = [['design', 'dbuPerMicron', 'diearea'],
                             ['components'],
                            ]
        if not self.ignore_nets:
            self.sections_grp.append(['nets'])
        self.n_elems_sections_grp = sum([len(x) for x in self.sections_grp])
        self.counter = modules.SharedCounter(0)
        self.events = [Event()]
        self.design = ''
        modules.debug_log.print_repr([self.__repr__()])

    #
    def run(self):
        for curr_file in self.def_file_design:
            ifile = open(curr_file,'r')
            file_string = ifile.read()
            ifile.close()
            self.parse_all(file_string)

    # Create a process for each section to parse
    def parse_all(self, file_string):
        manager = Manager()
        shared_dict = manager.dict()
        jobs = []
        for sections in self.sections_grp:
            p = Process(target=self.parse_sections, args=(sections, file_string, shared_dict))
            jobs.append(p)
            p.start()

        # Wait for the workers to finish
        for job in jobs:
            job.join()

        for sections in self.sections_grp:
            for section in sections:
                getattr(self, 'handle_' + section)(shared_dict)


    # Spawn the processes from each group of self.sections_grp
    def parse_sections(self, sections, file_string, shared_dict):
        for section in sections:
            to_parse = getattr(self, 'parse_' + section)
            for t, s, e in to_parse().scanString(file_string):
                shared_dict.update(t.asDict())
                break


    # Parse the DESIGN section of a .DEF file
    def parse_design(self):
        ...
        return design

    # Parse the UNITS DISTANCE MICRONS section of a .DEF file
    def parse_dbuPerMicron(self):
        ...
        return dbuPerMicron

    # Parse the DIEAREA section of a .DEF file
    def parse_diearea(self):
        ...
        return diearea

    # Parse the COMPONENTS section of a .DEF file
    def parse_components(self):
        self.events[0].wait()  # Wait for event[0] to finish
        
        EOL = pp.LineEnd().suppress()
        linebreak = pp.Suppress(";" + pp.LineEnd())
        identifier = pp.Word(pp.alphanums + '._“!<>/[]$#$%&‘*+,/:<=>?@[\]^_`{|}~')
        number = pp.pyparsing_common.number
        word = pp.Word(pp.alphas)
        LPAR = pp.Suppress('(')
        RPAR = pp.Suppress(')')
        ORIENT = (pp.Keyword('N')
                | pp.Keyword('S')
                | pp.Keyword('E')
                | pp.Keyword('W')
                | pp.Keyword('FN')
                | pp.Keyword('FS')
                | pp.Keyword('FE')
                | pp.Keyword('FW'))
        pt = LPAR + pp.OneOrMore(number | pp.Keyword('*')) + RPAR  # pair of x,y
        
        components_id = pp.Keyword('COMPONENTS')
        end_components_id = pp.Keyword("END COMPONENTS").suppress()
        begin_comp = pp.Suppress(pp.Keyword('-'))
        ws_comp = pp.Suppress(pp.Keyword('+'))  # parameter division in components

        # compName
        compName = (identifier('comp_name') + identifier('cell')
                   ).setResultsName('compName')

        ...
        ...
        ...

        subcomponent = pp.Group(begin_comp
                                + compName
                                + pp.Optional(EEQMASTER)
                                + pp.Optional(SOURCE)  # & because it can be in any order
                                + pp.Optional(PLACEMENT)
                                + pp.Optional(MASKSHIFT)
                                + pp.Optional(HALO)
                                + pp.Optional(ROUTEHALO)
                                + pp.Optional(WEIGHT)
                                + pp.Optional(REGION)
                                + pp.ZeroOrMore(PROPERTY)
                                + pp.Suppress(linebreak)
                               ).setResultsName('subcomponents', listAllMatches=True)

        components = pp.Group(pp.Suppress(components_id)
                                          + number('numComps')
                                          + pp.Suppress(linebreak)
                                          + pp.OneOrMore(subcomponent)
                                          + pp.Suppress(end_components_id)
                             ).setResultsName('COMPONENTS')

        return components
```

Comment: Can you isolate the time it takes to create the parser from the time it takes to do the actual parsing (the call to parseString, parseFile, searchString or scanString)? This will help focus the analysis of your issue.

Comment: Sure, I will be able to do it in a couple of hours...

Comment: @Paul, I put the python files as well as the def files at [github](https://github.com/rviera/DEF_pyparsing.git). `parser_def_1.py` takes around 35s to complete and `parser_def_2.py` around 18s in the computer I'm now. parser_def_1.py is the original. _2 is using the vars inside each method and _3 is a version without multiprocessing. Feel free to contribute if you can. I will add the timers you suggested ASAP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The likely culprit seems likely to be staring at you here:

> ... in Ex1 the variables used by PyParsing are declared as globals before the class.

```
from multiprocessing import (Process, Manager, Event)
```

Multiprocessing may be reloading or interacting with this in a funny way.  Is `DEF.sections_grp` always a single list (e.g. 1 process) in your timing tests?

Comment: `['design', 'dbuPerMicron', 'diearea']` is run in parallel with `['components']` in this example.

Comment: I put the python files as well as the def files at [github](https://github.com/rviera/DEF_pyparsing.git). `parser_def_1.py` takes around 35s to complete and `parser_def_2.py` around 18s in the computer I'm now. parser_def_1.py is the original. _2 is using the vars inside each method and _3 is a version without multiprocessing. Feel free to contribute if you can. I will continue to investigate, but it looks like to be something to do with multiprocessing indeed. I will accept your answer after I investigate more. Thank you.

Comment: Glad I was able to point you in the right direction, sorry the answer was not more complete - life marches on :)